# SQLKata: Incorrectly adding "" in query for SqlLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlkata

I am using SqlKata to create Db query for SqlLite.

```
var compiler = new SqliteCompiler();
var result = compiler.Compile(query);

var query = new Query()
        .Select("client.Id")
        .From("schema.client as c")
        .Join("schema.order as o", "c.Id", "o.ClientId")
        .WhereIn("c.Id", new[] {1,2,3});
```

Expected sql should be:

```
SELECT client.Id FROM "schema.client" AS c 
INNER JOIN "schema.order" AS o ON c.Id = o.ClientId
WHERE c.Id IN (1,2,3)
```

But I am getting:

```
SELECT "client"."Id" FROM "schema"."client" AS c 
INNER JOIN "schema"."order" AS o ON "c"."Id" = "o"."ClientId"
WHERE "c"."Id" IN (1,2,3)
```

1. When I am using schema `schema.order` I should not have in query: "schema"."order"
2. Only table name should be with "". For example it should be: `WHERE c.Id` and not: `WHERE "c"."Id"`

I would like to know, if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: Could you point out the exact differences that are "wrong"? I'm having a really hard time finding them

Comment: @MindSwipe Look at the quoting of `schema.order`.

Comment: 1. When I am using scheme: "schema.order" I should not have in querry: "schema"."order"
2. Only table name should be with "".
For example it should be:
 WHERE c.Id not:WHERE "c"."Id"

Comment: Neither of those look right. `"schema"."order"` is correct for referring to a table named `order` in an attached database named `schema`. But `"c.Id"` should be `"c"."Id"`.

Comment: Identifiers such as columns, aliases and tables should be wrapped inside `"` as recommended by SQLite
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html